# polymer focus() on <paper-input> or <core-input> element

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is there a way to focus core-input or paper-input element?

What I want to achieve is: set cursor to input element so user can start typing.

This way he will not be forced to click on element before writing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`core-input` is missing `focus()/blur()` API, this is essentially a bug.

For now you can do this:

`<reference to a core/paper-input>.$.input.focus();`

Comment: $.input.focus() worked. It will be OK for now. Thank you for fast answer! :)

Comment: What's the Dart equivalent?

Comment: `core-input` now supports `focus()` but with a little catch, see my solution below

Answer (score 8):

core-input has now a `.focus()` method it's delegating to the internal 's `focus()`

From the `core-input.html` code:

```
focus: function() {
    this.$.input.focus();
  }
```

What means that in your own code you need to call it like following:

```
elem[0].focus()
```

In my own case, I am calling `focus` from a `timeout`. In this case a `bind` is necessary for `core-input` to make a right use of `this`:

```
$timeout(elem[0].focus.bind(elem[0]));
```

Comment: All `elem[0].focus.bind(elem[0])` does is produce a function (that is immediately discarded); it doesn't actually call `focus()`. Did you mean to type something else?

Comment: Hey Scott thanks for that. I just edited the solution like you said. I have this executed inside a `timeout` which receives a function, so just how I discarded those brackets. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but this `elem[0].focus.bind(elem[0])()` is not necessary. `elem[0].focus()` is enough.

Comment: @ScottMiles no worries, software is all about the details. The need for `bind` is a special case and I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

.focusAction(); works in a slightly nicer way, the floating headers will react properly if enabled.

Answer (score 0):

for those using Polymer 1.0 (not OP at time of post)

For the first paper-input you can set focus with this:

```
        $('paper-input input').first().focus();
```

you can also select by id for a specific paper-input:

```
        $('#myValue input').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Polymer 2.0 use

this.$.id-of-the-Element.focus();

so if your element is like 
`<paper-input id="myInputElement" type="number" name="myInputElement"> </paper-input>`

Then you would do 
`this.$.myInputElement.focus();`