# Best way to set .focus() on an InputElement in my overlay/dialog Polymer element?

Tags: dart-polymer

I have a button that brings up a dialog overlay with a standard `<input>` in it. The dialog is a Polymer element. How do I set the focus of the element? I tried doing it in the toggleOverlay() method that opens the overlay, and in the attached() that I learned is actually called even before the overlay is open.

```
InputElement get subject => $['subject'];
subject.focus();
```

Where and how do I get this to work? Related to [polymer focus() on <paper-input> or <core-input> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496590/polymer-focus-on-paper-input-or-core-input-element)?