# How to focus a paper-input with Polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

This question is a follow-up to this one: [polymer focus() on <paper-input> or <core-input> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496590/polymer-focus-on-paper-input-or-core-input-element#)

How can I focus in a `paper-input` element using the Javascript API ?

(using Polymer 1.0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have an element:

```
<paper-input id="my-input" label="What's on your mind?"></paper-input>
```

**paper-input** is a wrapper for business logic and stylish of a more deep-down `input` element which you can reach through:

```
document.getElementById('my-input').$.input
```

To focus, just write:

```
document.getElementById('my-input').$.input.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this! You should however for the sake of prettiness use `this.$.my-input.$.input.focus()`. Also, if you happen to do this the same time as the `paper-input` is being shown, you should call `focus()` inside a `setTimeout(function(){...}, 0}` call.

Comment: by the time I wrote `document.getElementById('my-input')` I used a `<paper-input>` not inside a Polymer Element template, that is why

Answer (score 10):

`<paper-input autofocus></paper-input>` will automatically focus immediately, or if you'd prefer to control the timing yourself in Javascript you can use `paperInput.$.input.focus()`.

Comment: thanks, i didn't mean *autofocus* though, check my schizophrenic answer, that is what I wanted to do.