# Paper-Input tabindex and focus

Tags: input, focus, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am using instances of `paper-input` inside a `paper-drawer`. I want the first `paper-input` to be focused when the drawer opens under certain circumstances. Here is the code for the input:

```html
<paper-input id="myValue" label="Value" class="inline myValue" value="{{thing.myValue}}" tabindex="1"></paper-input>
```

When I inspect this element via the console, however, both `element.focus()` and `element.$.input.focus()` (per [polymer focus() on <paper-input> or <core-input> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496590/polymer-focus-on-paper-input-or-core-input-element)) return `undefined` and neither changes the focus state of the `paper-input`.

How do I programmatically focus the element?

Comment: The title of this question includes 'tabindex', but the question doesn't ask about it, nor to any of the answers address it. Does tabindex functionality work with paper-input?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that the input is not yet attached to the dom, so it could not focus, you've tried to do `this.$.idElement.focus();` asynchronous? Try to doing as follows when you need to make focus:

```
this.async(function(){
   this.$.inputId.focus();
},someTime);//someTime is optional
```

Comment: I've tried the focus method from the developer console. Would that still be the case when I'm working with the rendered page?

Answer (score -2):

Using jQuery, for the first paper-input you can set focus with this:

```
        $('paper-input input').first().focus();
```

you can also select by id for a specific paper-input:

```
        $('#myValue input').focus();
```

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Comment: Thanks tony, I updated the answer to indicate that the answer uses jQuery.