# How to focus a paper-input in lit-element

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

I have a `<paper-input>` element on my page that I want selected when the page loads. I tried to focus it when the page is first updated but that hasn't worked.

```
firstUpdated() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#input').focus();
}
```

[The paper-input page](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-input/elements/paper-input#description) suggests that setting `tabindex` is required for `input.focus()` to work, so I did that as well and it did not work. I have also tried the solutions suggested for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496590/polymer-focus-on-paper-input-or-core-input-element) about `paper-input` in polymer, and none of them worked.

Is there a way to focus a `paper-input` in lit-element?

Comment: Have you tried using `paper-input`'s [`autoFocus`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-input/elements/paper-input#property-autofocus) property?

Comment: This should also be possible on a basic HTML input using the focus function. The autofocus attribute works for me though

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack that I'm using that I maybe would not use in production, but it maybe it can serve as inspiration.

```
focusDescription() {
    let descriptionElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("description") as any
    let descriptionInputElement = descriptionElement.inputElement.children[0]
    descriptionInputElement.inputElement.children[0].focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ref`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#ref) to get a reference to the element, and then use that to set focus:

```
inputRef: Ref<PaperInputElement> = createRef();
​
render() {
    return html`<paper-input ${ref(this.inputRef)}></paper-input>`;
}
​
firstUpdated() {
    this.inputRef.value.focus();
}
```

Note that Polymer's `autofocus` *won't* work as it relies on Polymer's shady DOM shims and breaks focus trapping if you use `<paper-dialog>`, see https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/issues/282